# What is DNS format error log in syslog

Tags: linux, dns, format, syslog

I checked all my logs from my Linux server and I saw :

```
Sep  2 10:08:02 ns210585 named[4515]: DNS format error from 83.231.128.34#53 resolving www.boursorama.com/AAAA for client 127.0.0.1#54346: invalid response
Sep  2 07:52:34 ns210585 named[4515]: error (connection refused) resolving 'ns3.freeavailabledomains.com/A/IN': 31.31.79.225#53
Sep  2 07:52:34 ns210585 named[4515]: error (connection refused) resolving 'ns1.freeavailabledomains.com/AAAA/IN': 31.31.79.225#53
Sep  2 07:52:34 ns210585 named[4515]: error (connection refused) resolving 'ns2.freeavailabledomains.com/AAAA/IN': 31.31.79.225#53
Sep  2 07:52:34 ns210585 named[4515]: error (connection refused) resolving 'ns3.freeavailabledomains.com/AAAA/IN': 31.31.79.225#53
Sep  2 07:52:34 ns210585 named[4515]: error (connection refused) resolving 'ns1.freeavailabledomains.com/A/IN': 31.31.79.225#53
Sep  2 07:52:40 ns210585 named[4515]: error (connection refused) resolving 'lejournaldessables.fr/A/IN': 88.190.237.179#53
Sep  2 07:52:41 ns210585 named[4515]: error (unexpected RCODE SERVFAIL) resolving 'www.apur.org/AAAA/IN': 109.169.14.200#53
```

and I have also other kind of logs but with other domains as lefigaro.com

Why boursorama or lefigaro ?

Is there something malicious ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your name server queried another nameserver, and claims that in received an invalid response.

This is not unusual, happens all the time. There are a lot of gremlins running around on the intertubes.